# launch browser in android app

Tags: android, web, launch

I am new to android programming. I try to develop one android app (has to be app so it can be managed by application manager control) to open the particular website in external browser in Android studio.
I know I can use webview control. But the problem is the user has to click the screen and then open the site in the external browser so two windows, app windows and external browser, are open in this case. My goal is the user clicks the app icon one time and the site will be opened in external browser without webview window.

Any suggestion or sample codes or pointing to some source for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there you will find the next answer :)

```
Intent browserX = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserX);
```

don't forget the permissions  to the manifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```